# Volume slider not behaving properly

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am not so good in iOS. I have added a volume slider in my app from storyboard and wrote one line code to change the volume when the slider is moved. But the problem is that it is not working properly. For a big section in the middle, its not doing anything, just working at the ends. I have written this code:

in **First.h**

```
    UIView *viewVolume;
    MPVolumeView *_mpVolumeView;
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;


}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MPVolumeView *mpVolumeView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *viewVolume;

-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id)sender;
@end
```

in **First.m**

```
@synthesize slider;
@synthesize mpVolumeView = _mpVolumeView;


-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    player.volume = slider.value;

}
```

Here is the image of **StoryBoard**:

[image]

Comment: How is your question directly connected to the IDE you are using?

Comment: The StoryBoard is provided by IDE.

Comment: Right, now that you added it, things make more sense. However, why are you using your own slider and not the one provided by `MPVolumeView`?

Comment: Actually I am very confused in this. I am unable to think what to write to make it work. Now since you have all the parts related to volume slider, can you please suggest where shall the change be done to make it work.?

Comment: When you change `player.volume` programmatically it does work right?

Comment: Ya the volume slider is working, but the problem is iots working only at the ends. In middle no effect at the volume..

Answer (score 0):

Bind slider min and max values. Check in continuous button.

```
    [slider setMaximumValue:4.4];
    [slider setMinimumValue:0.0];
    [slider setContinuous:YES];
```

Comment: You can do it with attribute inspector (Right side menu).

Comment: Sorry was trying.. Not working. Actually that was already set from 0-10. But still I tried but no use..